# Имитация клика по карте при поиске Yandex Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

И так, есть карта, на карту выводятся полигоны, при клике на полигон выводится баллун с информацией об этом полигоне:
[image: Пример отображение баллуна]

Так же на карту добавлен поиск, при вводе адреса он ставит метку и выводит СВОЙ баллун.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли как ни будь сделать так, что бы при нахождении адреса в области полигона выводился баллун этого полигона (как на первой картинке), как будто туда кликнули мышью?

Comment: В теории можно отследить клик и потом имитировать его, это решает JavaScript. Дальше в гугл по запросу: `"Имитация клика на JS"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все получилось! Вот фрагмент того что получилось.

```
searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function (e) {
        highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[e.get('index')]);
    });
    function highlightResult(obj) {
        // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта.
        var coords = obj.geometry.getCoordinates(),
        // Находим полигон, в который входят переданные координаты.
            polygon = myObjects.searchContaining(coords).get(0);
        if (polygon) {                              
            polygon.options.set('fillOpacity', 0.2);
            polygon.balloon.open();
        }}}
```

Только почему то работает это только в песочнице(

Comment: Может быть некорректное подключение API Яндекс Карт на странице или проблемы с ключом API. Стоит написать в поддержку для проверки - maps-api@support.yandex.ru

Comment: Не, там битрикс немного чудит, причина уже понятна, осталось придумать как починить)

Answer (score 0):

Открыть балун объекта можно прямым запросом, который также проскроллит карту к объекту:

```
myPolygon.balloon.open();
```

Определить нужный полигон можно через [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.html), пример с которым показан в песочнице:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones

В этом же примере рассматривается и отслеживание выбора результата поиска:

```
    searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function (e) {
       ...
    });
```